# I can't find app module in android studio

Tags: android

I cloned empty git repository to Android Studio using "Get from Version Control" menu and then I created module like this:

> New > Module > Phone & Tablet module

After creating module, I am not able to find app directory.
Normal project looks like this: [normal case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jacqH.png), but my project is look like this [my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppTlK.png).
When I click on **Sync project with gradle files**.
An error occurs.

```
Cannot resolve external dependency
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72 because no
repositories are defined. Required by
    project :
```

I tried to find solution. But I couldn't find why this error occured.

Comment: Could you share with your project build.gradle code?

Comment: `buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to you project build.gradle

```
repositories { 
      mavenCentral() 
}
```